# В datatable попадают не все данные

Tags: django, datatable, celery

В `molels.py` существует модель

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet)
    hash = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Тип транзакции")
    raw_transaction = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='source', verbose_name='Отправитель', blank=True, null=True)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='destination', verbose_name='Получатель', blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Сумма')
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
    fee = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Комиссия')
    result = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Результат')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hash
```

В `views.py` определяю отображение с помощью django-datatables-view

```
class TransactionsJsonView(BaseDatatableView):
    model = Transaction

    _undefined_user_string = 'Неизвестный'

    columns = ['timestamp', 'result', 'source', 'amount']

    order_columns = ['timestamp', 'result', 'source', 'amount']

    max_display_length = 500

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'source':
            try:
                return '{username}'.format(username=row.source.username)
            except AttributeError as e:
                return self._undefined_user_string
        elif column == 'amount':
            return '{}'.format(row.amount)
        else:
            return super(TransactionsJsonView, self).render_column(row, column)

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        # get user input from sSearch
        search = self.request.GET.get(u'sSearch', None)
        if search == self._undefined_user_string:
            # Поиск по неизвестным отправителям транзакций.
            query = Q(source=None)
            qs = qs.filter(query, wallet__user=self.request.user)
        elif search:
            # Указания полей и способа фильтрации
            query = Q(timestamp__icontains=search) | Q(result__icontains=search) | Q(
                amount__icontains=search) | Q(source__username__icontains=search)
            qs = qs.filter(query, wallet__user=self.request.user)
        else:
            # если поиск не определён необходимо отфильтровать транзакции по кошелькам аутентифицированного пользователя
            qs = qs.filter(wallet__user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

В js инициализирую datatable и определяю его обновление:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var txTable = $('#transactionsTable').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": lang_url
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": transactions_list_json_url,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bStateSave": true
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        txTable.ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload
    }, 500);
});
```

Параллельно работает celery и обновляет таблицу с транзакциями:

```
@shared_task
def monitoring():
    wallets = Wallet.objects.all()

    for wallet in wallets:
        if wallet.user.is_authenticated:
            transactions_result = Profile.update_transactions(wallet)
```

Определение update_transactions:

```
def update_transactions(wallet):
    """
    Выполняет получение транзакций для указанного кошелька

    :param wallet: кошелёк, из которого получается адрес для обновления транзакций
    :return: new_transactions_list - список новых транзакций (объекты модели)
    """
    transactions = api.get_transactions(wallet.address)
    if transactions:
        new_transactions_list = []
        for transaction in transactions['transactions']:
            try:
                defaults = Profile.parse_transaction(transaction, wallet)
                if defaults:
                    tx, tx_created = Transaction.objects.update_or_create(hash=defaults['hash'],
                                                                          defaults=defaults)

                    if tx_created:
                        new_transactions_list.append(tx)

            except Profile.UnsupportedTransaction as e:
                print e.message
            except Exception as e:
                print e.message
        return new_transactions_list
```

Периодически возникает ситуация, при которой обновляется datatable во время обновления таблицы celery. При этом в datatable могут вернуться не все данные.

В консоли браузера всё чисто. Если просмотреть детали ответа на запросы datatable, то можно заметить, что количество всех записей `iTotalRecords` всегда соответствует ожиданиям, а количество записей для отображения `iTotalDisplayRecords` иногда уменьшается.

Пока удалось локализовать файл `base_datatable_view.py` из пакета django-datatables-view и функцию `get_context_data` в которой происходит подготовка ответа:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.initialize(*args, **kwargs)

            qs = self.get_initial_queryset()

            # number of records before filtering
            total_records = qs.count()

            qs = self.filter_queryset(qs)

            # number of records after filtering
            total_display_records = qs.count()

            qs = self.ordering(qs)
            qs = self.paging(qs)

            # prepare output data
            if self.pre_camel_case_notation:
                aaData = self.prepare_results(qs)

                ret = {'sEcho': int(self._querydict.get('sEcho', 0)),
                       'iTotalRecords': total_records,
                       'iTotalDisplayRecords': total_display_records,
                       'aaData': aaData
                       }
            else:
                data = self.prepare_results(qs)

                ret = {'draw': int(self._querydict.get('draw', 0)),
                       'recordsTotal': total_records,
                       'recordsFiltered': total_display_records,
                       'data': data
                       }
            return ret
        except Exception as e:
            return self.handle_exception(e)
```

Похоже, что проблема возникает после выполнения строки `qs = self.filter_queryset(qs)`

Как реализовать периодическое обновление таблицы и не мешать при этом работе datatables?

Использую python2.7, django 1.11, django-datatables-view 1.16.0, celery 4.2.0. СУБД PostgreSQL 9.2.23. Всё работает на centos 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для задачи мониторинга применил `@transaction.atomic`

```
@shared_task
@transaction.atomic
def monitoring():
    ...
```